# Function that explodes string?

Tags: javascript, regex

With my current function:

http://piza.com/something returns `pizza.com`

How do I change it so it doesn't remove what's after `/` but keeps removing http, https and www?

E.G:
http://piza.com/something/1 should return `pizza.com/something/1`

```
function cleanUrl(url) { 
    return url.replace(/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([^\/]+)(\/.*)?$/gi,"$4");
}
```

Comment: Do you only want to get rid of the www or all subdomains all together?

Comment: Are you trying to remove the initial double forward-slashes in something like //piza.com/something as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try before you ask. So many regex questions on stackoverflow are basically 'write my regex'.

Anyway, something like this should work (untested):

```
function cleanUrl(url) { 
    return url.replace(/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?/gi,"");
}
```

Comment: honestly I'd have tried but I don't understand the code even the slightest

Comment: @Liso22 http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm and http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/you-dont-know-anything-about-regular-expressions/ :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that will work.

```
return url.replace(/(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?/gi,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (url.indexOf('http://') == 0) url = url.substr(7);
else if (url.indexOf('https://') == 0) url = url.substr(8);
if (url.indexOf('www.') == 0) url = url.substr(4);
return url;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return url.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regular expression replacement:

```
var url = "http://piza.com/something/1";
var output = url.replace(/^http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?/, "");
```

To explain the regular expression:

```
^http - string starts with "http"
(s)?  - followed by an optional "s" in "https"
:\/\/ - followed by "://"
(www\.) - followed an an optional "www."
```

Then, replace whatever part of that match that you found with nothing, leaving only the rest of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I will also add to the plethora of answers (since I worked it out).

A small modification to your original script will work:

```
^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(([^\/]+)(\/.*)?)$
```

so you'd have

```
function cleanUrl(url) { 
    return url.replace(/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(([^\/]+)(\/.*)?)$/gi,"$4");
}
```

The main difference here is I changed the part just after the www check to capture the rest of your regular expression as a group.  It's really all about groups.

Your original string / regex combo `^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([^\/]+)(\/.*)?$` returned the following groups:

0. http://piza.com/something/1

1. http://

2. undefined

3. undefined

4. pizza.com

5. /something/1

The  revised string /regex combo `^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(([^\/]+)(\/.*)?)$` returns:

0. http://piza.com/something/1

1. http://

2. undefined

3. undefined

4. pizza.com/something/1

5. pizza.com

6. /something/1

Any time you have a parenthesis pair you create a group.  In your case, you wanted a group that captured everything after the www part, so that is where I made a new group to capture everything else.

BTW, you can easily try out these regex's online.  I used [JavaScript RegExp Example: Regular Expression Tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) and hit the "Show Match" button to see what your groups were returning.